# triggering sequential animated.css animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, animate.css

I'm trying to animate elements sequentially by using jQuery. The approach that I'm trying to accomplish is to add "animated fadeInDown" classes on each element that should be animated, with a 500 milisecond delay.

The problem that I'm experiencing is that jQuery (or if I use setTimetout function) will trigger all animations at the same time.

Here's my code:

```
$('.row-assets .asset').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i++) * 500).addClass('animated').addClass('fadeInDown');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: depending on your skill level and available time, maybe check out the GreenSock jQuery animation library - http://www.greensock.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addClass()` is not part of the jQuery animation queue, and is therefore not affected by `delay()`. A proper use of setTimeout should work:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/3tQ7T/)**

```
var addClassToEl = function($el) {
    $el.addClass('animated fadeInDown');
};

$('.row-assets .asset').each(function(i, el) {
    setTimeout(function() {addClassToEl($(el))}, i++ * 500);
});
```

You'll have to make sure that your classes have appropriate CSS transitions on them if you want to animate their changes.